# Surround widgets option not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, widget, android-studio-3.0

I am a beginner programmer in Android Studio (Kotlin). While playing around with rows and columns of the text composables, I somehow disabled the surround widgets option. I am unable to turn it on myself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you need hints, so for that if on windows then press Alt + Enter and on Mac Option + Enter.

Comment: I have already tried what you said, and the dialog box in the screenshot I have shared is the result..

Answer (score 0):

[image: View image]

try going in window and restore default layout

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the Text composable.
Then choose main menu item "Code" -> "Surround with..."
In submenu that pops up in code select "Configure Live Templates..."
Select "Intentions"
Select the Tick box against "Surround with widget" under the Compose Android section.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu4pu.png)